# R: glm (multiple linear regression) ignores/removes some predictor variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

**I have posted this question before, but I believe that I had not explained the problem well and that it was over-complicated, so I deleted my previous post and I am posting this one instead. I am sorry if this caused any inconvenience.**

I also apologize in advance for not being able to provide example data, I am using very large tables, and what I am trying to do works fine with simpler examples, so providing example data cannot help. It has always worked for me until now. So I am just trying to get your ideas on what might be the issue. But if there is any way I could provide more information, do let me know.

So, I have a vector corresponding to a response variable and a table of predictor variables. The response vector is numeric, the predictor variables (columns of the table) are in the binary format (0s and 1s).

I am running the glm function (multivariate linear regression) using the response vector and the table of predictors:

```
fit <- glm(response ~ as.matrix(predictors), na.action=na.exclude)
coeff <- as.vector(coef(summary(fit))[,4])[-1]
```

When I have been doing that in the past, I would extract the vector of regression coefficient to use it for further analysis.

The problem is that now the regression returns a vector of coefficients which is missing some values. Essentially some predictor variables are not attributed a coefficient at all by glm. But there are no error messages.

The summary of the model looks normal, but some predictor variables are missing like I mentioned. Most other predictors have assigned data (coefficient, pvalue, etc.).
About 30 predictors are missing from the model, over 200.

I have tried using different response variables (vectors), but I am getting the same issue, although the missing predictors vary depending on the response vector...

Any ideas on what might be going on? I think this can happen if some variables have 0 variance, but I have checked that. There are also no NA values and no missing values in the tables.

What could cause glm to ignore/remove some predictor variables?

Any suggestion is welcome!

**EDIT:** I found out that the predictors that were removed has values identical to another predictor. There should still be a way to keep them, and they would get the same regression coefficient for example

Comment: If you have two predictors that have the same value, then your model suffers from multicollinearity and cannot be estimated. You should make sure your predictors are independent before attempting to fit a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit explains why you are not getting those variables. That was going to be my first question. (This question would be better posed on Cross validated because it is not an R error, it is a problem with your model.)

They would not get the same coefficients: Say you have a 1:1 relationship, `Y = X + e`, Then fit simple model `Y ~ X + X`. Each `X` is going to be assigned ANY value such that the sum is equal to 1. There is no solution. `Y = 0.5X + 0.5X` may be the most obvious to us, but `Y = 100X -99X` is just as valid.

You also cannot have any predictors that are linear sums of other predictors for the same reason.

If you really want those values you can generate them from what you have. However I do not recommend it because the assumptions are going to be on very thin ice.

Comment: Thank you! That explains my problem.

Comment: It appears that most of the lost predictors were duplicates, but a few are not. What do you mean by "predictors that are linear sums of other predictors"?

Comment: That column of your X matrix can be generated by a linear sum of other columns. For example the vector `(1 1 0)` can be generated with the vectors `(1 0 1)` and `(0 -1 1)`. Even though all three are technically different, a model cannot come up with predictions for all three. (If you want to read up more on this look for matrix Rank. A linear model is effectively projecting your data down onto a subspace, your predictors need to form a basis of that subspace. Or something like that it has been a long time since linear algebra.)